# Allocating space and concatenating to a unsigned char array in c

Tags: c, realloc

I'm creating an image compressor for a project. I generate codes for the values in the image in such a way that for every grey value (from 0-254) there is a char* code in an array called codeArray (Huffman Encoding).

A requirement is to have a function which returns unsigned char*. I go through every pixel and convert the grey value of that pixel to a code using the codeArray.

I need to make the unsigned char array grow dynamically as more grey values are converted and concatenated to the end of the array.

```
    unsigned char* encodedString = malloc(sizeof(char));    

    int width = image->width; //width and height of image structure
    int height = image->height;
    int row, col;
    for(row = 0; row<height; row++)
        for(col = 0; col<width; col++)
        {
            int value = image->pixel[row][col]; //gets the grey value

            encodedString = realloc(encodedString, (strlen(encodedString)+strlen(codeArray[value])));

            strcat(encodedString, codeArray[value]);

        }
```

I tried running this with a print statement after the strcat and found it printed until there were 24 characters then started printing garbage and then Seg faulted.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `strlen(encodedString)` on an uninitialized buffer. This is undefined behaviour. You need to zero-terminate the initial contents of `encodedString`.

```
unsigned char* encodedString = malloc(1);
//check for malloc errors 
encodedString[0] = '\0';
```

It looks like you get away with that error, but then immediately commit another one. Your `realloc` makes space for `strlen(encodedString)+strlen(codeArray[value])` but you have forgotten to allocate room for the zero terminator. Presumably that's what causes `strcat` to bomb. Fix that problem by adding one to the size parameter to `realloc`.

As @Lou points out the performance of your realloc strategy may be poor. You may be better to allocate the buffer once at the beginning of the function since presumably you can put a relatively tight upper bound on its size.

And you also should not ever write `ptr = realloc(ptr, ...)` since you won't be able to recover from a failure of `realloc` and will always leak. But that's really a nuance in comparison to the other faults.

Comment: +1. More or less my observation, except that I like to preach `realloc` dangers at every opportunity ;)

Comment: @David - Not to mention the in efficiency of calling realloc() once for every value you are adding to the encoded string. Either calculate how much space you will need and allocate ahead of time or at least use some binary growth of the encodedString (i.e. double the size of the encodedString array each time you need to increase the size).

Comment: @larsmans re. realloc, I know what you mean but I kind of felt that the main thrust should be the more glaring errors. Every question of this nature makes me appreciate even more the joys of languages with real string data types.

Comment: Thanks! I've never been very strong with allocating memory, and am never really sure if I've done it right. Also, I know Im suppose to allocate to a seperate pointer and do error checking-just wanted to keep it clean and simple.